# Help inserting iframe into Joomla 1.5.9

Tags: templates, iframe, joomla

I've done some research and learned that for Joomla 1.5.9 to work with iframe tags you must set permissions in article manager > parameters > filtering groups to whitelist the super administrator, and then set user manager > select user > user editor to "Editor - No Editor". After doing this, then opening an article, opening the html editor and inserting the iframe like so:

```
<iframe src="http://thewebsite.tumblr.com/" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

The editor continues to strip out the iframe code. Why would this happen?! I'm sure all of the settings I've mentioned earlier are set according to the tutorials I've come across. Are there any factors I need to take into consideration that I'm missing? Is there another way to insert an iframe into a custom template?

I hope someone can help!!

Answer (score 0):

Inside an Article you are best of using a plugin :

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/4144/details

it gives you the ability to insert an iframe by using e.g. {iframe width="90%" height="300" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes"}url{/iframe} also within the TinyMCEeditor.

If you don't need antyhing else inside the article you can use menu item/link. Internal Link - Wrapper
When the Wrapper link is selected, it expands to display the Wrapper layout. This is used to show an external web site inside a page in your web site, using an HTML IFrame. The external web site is contained inside the Wrapper. You can navigate to different pages in the wrapped web site, all inside the page of your web site.

http://docs.joomla.org/Help16:Menus_Menu_Item_Wrapper